# Delphi XE4 What do I have to include to use the function FmxHandleToObjC

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have just installed XE4 and I am trying to complie some sampel apps for osx from the web.

I can't compile as I get "Undeclared identifer FmxHandleToObjC" error

I have setup the SDK and cant find any help on the web.

Any ideas?

Comment: Grep for `FmxHandleToObjC` text in `c:\RAD Studio\11.0\source\*.pas` files

Answer (score 2):

That function was defined in `FMX.Platform.Mac` in XE3 but has been removed in XE4. The replacement functionality appears to be `WindowHandleToPlatform`.